# completely disable zsh completion system

Tags: zsh

I am trying out fzf completion and want zsh completion / suggestions to be completely disabled.

I have not used the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Still it is giving some suggestions.

I used:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false
```

Still it is giving some suggestions.

I guess I am looking for something like

```
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compsys false
```

So that I can completely disable my suggestion / completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't,** —or at least, not without editing `fzf`'s completion code— because `fzf`'s completion [explicitly calls Zsh's built-in completion when it fails.](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/f2d44ab5a793906457f3d3384f09af085096138d/shell/completion.zsh#L312) `fzf`'s supplied completion simply isn't set up to handle every case. That's why it has to fall back to the built-in completion at some point.

Also note that `compinit` is not required for getting completions in Zsh. It's simply required for activating Zsh's *new* completion system. If you don't call `compinit`, you instead get Zsh's legacy completion system.

Comment: I think the trick is to use `bindkey -r '^I'`

Comment: @blueray Then you will not get `fzf`'s completions either.